# How to handled database using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have faced  one problem to getting values from database using RoR. I have min 100 million data. how can i get all the data using single query and min response time?

I want to get all the customer names during particular time period (we are using MySQL)

Comment: What database are you using? Are you able to use an ORM like ActiveRecord? What does the database schema look like? What is 10crores of data?

This question needs a lot of clarification before it can be answered.

Comment: You need to describe more details about the structure of your database (tables, fields) and scale (what is `10crores of data`?).

Comment: I handled some customer info its nearly 10crores of data I want to get all the customer name during particular time period?

Comment: What is "crores"? This word needs translation.

Comment: Aha, a crore is an Indian numerical unit. It is, I believe, 100 million.

Comment: My assumption therefore is that Ram is dealing with 100 million rows of data?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore

Comment: Please don't use Indian words or totally unclear requirements like "particular time period". If you have a time constraint, why are you not telling what it is?

Comment: Yes I have 100millions of data in my database.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your database structure, but generally you can limit your queries to select only data that you're interested in.  If (for example) your table is called `customers` and your model is `Customer` and the table has the fields `transaction_date` and `name` you might do...

```
start_date = Date.parse('2018-10-01')
end_date = Dae.parse('2018-10-31')

@customer_names = Customer.where(transaction_date: (start_date..end_date)).pluck(:name)
```

The `where` limit on date should make the results manageable.